# Can't find template for adding connection to database with Entity Framework, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I right-click on the project `> Add > New item > Data >` and I can't see the template for ADO.NET Entity Framework, it is not there?

I can see in the NuGet installer that Entity Framework is installed. I run Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 pro.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It should be there - it's called the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model"

It adds a `.edmx` file for database-first.

If you're doing code-first, just write the model and add a connection string in your config file.

Comment: I know, but the solution was not there. The solution is to repair visual studio 2012. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

In VS2012 you have to install "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" or "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" to get EF tooling

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to repair Visual Studio 2012, something got wrong in the installation.